# Transpose SQL Result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following sql query

```
SELECT  [POINT],[Timestamp],AvgValue=AVG(ValueNumeric)
FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Value] 
WHERE [Point] In (98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105) 
  AND Timestamp between DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) and GETDATE() 
Group by [timestamp],[Point] 
order by [Timestamp], [Point]
```

which returns table as below

[image]

but I need to transpose this as below

```
Timestamp|Point1|Value1|Point2|Value2|Point3|Value3|
```

Is this doable?

Comment: What is your rbms? you need google for PIVOT or DYNAMIC PIVOT  on your rdbms

Comment: If the number/values of the points are not fixed or known, then you'd need some dynamic SQL here.  You can find information on SO for this.

Comment: The pivot query is an often asked question among the sql tag on SO. Please make an effort and report back with issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)